# How can you specify which NSMenu is the main menu in a XIB file?

Tags: macos, interface-builder, xib, nsmenu

Long time iOS developer who's dipping his toes in the macOS world. Just trying to better understand how Mac apps work.

For non-storyboard applications based on a XIB, the template creates a default xib and inside is the application's main menu.

However, if I delete that XIB, then create a new one, how do I set up a menu to be the application's main menu? It seems to ignore whatever I create. Plus, when I add one, the graphic looks different than the original; here it's stacked vertically whereas the original had them stacked horizontally.

So, how can you create a second xib (in case you deleted the first one) and replace the main menu in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do two steps to change the main menu to a menu in another XIB file:

1. Change the *Main Interface* in *Deployment Info* in the *General* tab of the *Target* of your application to the new XIB file. [image]
2. Open the source code of the new XIB file and search for your new Main Menu. This is a XML tag named `menu`. Add an attribute named `systemMenu` with the value `main` to it. This should look like:

   ```
   <menu title="Second Menu" systemMenu="main" id="usV-GH-tFG" userLabel="New Main Menu">
   ```

Now, your app should use the new Main Menu as System Menu. Some submenus should also have `systemMenu` attributes with the values `apple`, `services`, `recentDocuments`, `font` or `window`. If you have made this change, the display in the Interface Builder also changes.

Building a new menu takes a little effort because you have to create quite a few submenus and entries.

But this way you can easily make mistakes, so you should better create a new Main Menu by copying an existing one.